# adding a virtual NIC to linux

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, network-interface

I'm using CentOS 6.5 on oracle VirtualBox.

In order to gain access to the internet, I've added a second network card connected to the physical network card of my pc.

I rebooted the virtual server and the network interface does not show on `ifconfig` and not on `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/`

How can I add the interface?

Is there another way to gain access to the internet by assigning a default gateway somewhere?

Comment: See this guide : https://www.thomas-krenn.com/en/wiki/Network_Configuration_in_VirtualBox

Comment: Thanks, but it's not exactly what I need. I know that I need 2 virtual network cards but I don't know how to make both active and working on linux.  @IjazKhan

Comment: does it show in `ifconfig -a` or `ip link show`?

Answer (score 1):

OK , then probably you should disable network manager and add manual entries in `/etc/network/interfaces` , skip wireless related things in this guide , just focus on adding Ethernet interfaces but it also says how to add extra wireless interface if you need. Adding Ethernet interface is simple though:

```
$ ip a show
```

Note the default Ethernet and wifi interfaces:
ip-a-show

It looks like our Ethernet port is eth0. Our WiFi radio is wlan0. Want to make this briefer?

```
$ ip a show | awk  '/^[0-9]: /{print $2}'
```

The output of this command will look something like this:

lo:
eth0:
wlan0:

Your gateway IP address is found with:

```
route -n
```

It provides access to destination 0.0.0.0 (everything). In the below image it is 192.168.0.1, which is perfectly nominal.

route-n

```
#Remove network manager
apt-get purge network-manager
```

Let’s do a bit of easy configuration in our /etc/networking/interfaces file. The format of this file is not difficult to put together from the man page, but really, you should search for examples first.
interfaces
Plug in your Ethernet port.

Basically, we’re just adding DHCP entries for our interfaces. Above you’ll see a route to another network that appears when I get a DHCP lease on my Ethernet port. Next, add this:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
auto wlan0
iface wlan0 inet dhcp
```

Next, enable and start the networking service:

```
sudo update-rc.d networking enable



sudo /etc/init.d/networking start
```

Let’s make sure this works, by resetting the port with these commands:

```
sudo ifdown eth0
sudo ip a flush eth0

    sudo ifup eth0
```

This downs the interface, flushes the address assignment to it, and then brings it up. Test it out by pinging your gateway IP: ping 192.168.0.1. If you don’t get a response, your interface is not connected or your made a typo.

Let’s “do some WiFi” next! We want to make an /etc/wpa_supplicant.conf file. Consider mine:

```
network={
ssid="CenturyLink7851"
scan_ssid=1
key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
psk="4f-------------ac"
}
```

Now we can reset the WiFi interface and put this to work:

```
sudo ifdown wlan0



sudo ip a flush wlan0

    sudo ifup wlan0



sudo wpa_supplicant -Dnl80211 -c /root/wpa_supplicant.conf -iwlan0 -B



sudo dhclient wlan0
```

That should do it. Use a ping to find out, and do it explicitly from wlan0, so it gets it’s address first:

```
$ ip a show wlan0 | grep "inet"

Presumably dhclient updated your /etc/resolv.conf, so you can also do a:

ping -I 192.168.0.45 www.yahoo.com
```

If you want to add another NIC then just keep on adding it in `/etc/network/interface` as guided above

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out.
basically what I did was to create a `ifcfg-eth1` file, i typed the most basic information in there saying it to receive the IP dynamically,
and then I issued `ifup eth1` and voila, it worked.
Thank you all.